# Is that a bug in Qt Creator analizer

Tags: c++11, qt-creator, stdmap, auto, stdset

While working with some code I experienced QT Creator performance degradation. Actually it launches a thread that occupies 100% CPU in an infinite loop: even closing the IDE process without killing it becomes impossible. This is fully reproducible on my machine. Before submitting a bug I wish to get a confirmation from other users and to collect some statistics for the versions of QT Creator, OS, compiler, STL, etc. The code requires C++11 and higher.

After some investigation I reduced my code to the shortest sample that reproduces the issue (don't look at the symantics of the code, the problem is in how does the IDE treats it):

```
#include <set>
int main() {
    std::set<int> s;
    auto iter = s.insert(1).first;
    iter->second;
    return 0;
}
```

The highlights:

- **auto** is important
- the same behavior can be reproduced with the **map** instead of the **set**
- **insert** is important as it returns not a simple iterator but a pair< iterator, bool>
- The line *iter->second* is symantically incorrect, but that is not important (you may use *std::set< std::pair>* to make it correct). The problem is that the IDE crashes after *iter->* whatever it could mean.

My configuration is: QT Creator 3.5.1 based on Qt 5.5.1 (MSVC 2013, 32 bit); Windows 10.

Comment: Qt Creator's bug track is the best place for such questions.

Comment: The bug tracker is the best place to submit a bug, but before submitting I wish to realize that I fully understand the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot has happened since Qt Creator 3.5. The code model is completely new, based on Clang. Hence, I cannot reproduce your problem with Qt Creator 4.9. (And yes, the old code model had several limitations and bugs.)

In general, always make sure you have the latest supported version of the software before you prepare a bug report.

Comment: Qt 5.5.1 is the latest version that supports WebKit.

Comment: Qt Webkit by itself is deprecated since quite some time (since 2014), most of all because of _security reasons_. Time to port over to Qt Webengine. Note that also Qt 5.5 is not supported since a year ago.

Comment: At the time when I started my project Qt WebEngine didn't support enough features that I needed. The security reasons were not a problem to me. So far Qt 5.5.1 is still in use, many people prefer it partually because of the WebKit.

Comment: Can confirm, I also have had the ClangCodeModel process get stuck in an infinite loop from old QtCreator versions. Definitely recommend upgrading - it will fix that bug, and you will get a much more pleasant development experience.